# Using jscodeshift, Is there a way to extract a node path from a collection if there is only one node path?

Tags: jscodeshift, codemod

I'm just getting started with writing CodeMods with `jscodeshift`. I noticed that the `find` method seems to always return a `Collection`. If there is only one node path in the collection is there an easy way to extract that node path?

For example, I can easily get the default export, of which there will only ever be one:

```js
j(file.source).find(j.ExportDefaultDeclaration)
```

However, this returns a collection, which I then need to call `forEach` on to process the one and only node.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `.get(0)` will get the first Node Path in a Collection, so

```
j(file.source).find(j.ExportDefaultDeclaration).get(0);
```

would return the Node Path in question.